# Is the optical disk drive an input device?

Tags: computer-architecture

I have read online and seen websites saying the optical disk drive is a storage device. In my opinion, the optical disk drive only writes data to the optical disk so it's not a storage device, am I wrong??

Comment: [en.wikipedia on optical disk drives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_disc_drive): `a disc drive that uses [light for] reading or writing data`.